# How to open and later close another program from c++ in another terminal?

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, posix

I would like to open some other programs from my c++ code in linux and save the handle/pid so I can terminate them later. It is important that the programs that I start open up in a new terminal window for each application and that I can pass arguments to the programs at startup. In windows, I can do it with CreateProcess and TerminateProcess.

In linux, tried popen() and pclose(). Currently, I try to do it with posix_spawn(). I can open another program and I get the pid, the only thing I didn't manage to do is to open the program in another terminal window.

My current Code is :

```
std::string path = "exampleProg";
pid_t pid;
status = posix_spawn(&pid, path.c_str(), NULL, NULL, v, NULL);
```

Comment: Why is the terminal window important?

Comment: Maybe initialize path to something?   At least you might get less snarky responses.

Comment: I would like to see the outputs of the programs while they run.

Comment: If you you want to start a terminal, then maybe it would be a good idea to actually start a terminal. The shell command `xterm vi` will start a new `xterm` process and display `vi` in it. How to change this to start your favorite terminal, and do it from `c`, is left as an exercise for the reader

Comment: If you just want to see the outputs of the programs as they run, then an alternative approach may be to send the outputs of those commands to files, rather than to terminal windows. Don't get stuck on insisting a terminal window. An approach that makes sense on Windows may be suboptimal on Linux.

Comment: HAL9000 is right.  Your linux (probably) has several terminal emulators.  I happen to have gnome-terminal installed.  So I do "man gnome-terminal" and inspect the output. In this case, note that the command option  "--command=STRING" where STRING can identify any other executable.  Then note that the options "Executes the argument to this option inside the terminal".  Try it ... Or google for tutorials.  Note that I prefer popen (and have used fork).  I recommend that you avoid any 'exec' form of command.

Comment: The parameters of gnome-terminal even allow run time control of 
"--geometry=GEOMETRY   X geometry specification (see "X" man page), can be specified once per window to be opened."   The option --working-directory=DIRNAME  can set a unique working directory for each terminal you open.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
system("xterm \"/PATH_TO_EXECUTABLE\"");
```

Comment: `x-terminal-emulator` is particular to certain Linux distributions, especially Debian-derived ones.

Comment: I don't have `xterm` on my system, only `konsole`. Truth is there is no portable way to do this, you have to let the user configure it. And the *alternatives* way (`x-terminal-emulator`) Oblivion used at first is a common way to do that, even if not ubiquitous.

Comment: It is trivial to find out how to install gnome-terminal or others.  i.e. sudo apt ...

Comment: thanks Oblivion, unfortunately this way I can't get the pid for closing the application later.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to HAL9000. I was a little bit at loss. I now do it with

```
popen("xterm -e ...","r")
```